# Swift: Set UIButton Image with CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cgrect, uigraphicscontext

I'd like to set the image of a `UIButton`, but without creating all of the assets at different sizes.

Since it should be just a grey rectangle, with some text on top, I'm trying to do this by creating a `CGRect`. The title is displayed as desired, and the button can be clicked for the region described by the `CGRect`, but when I run the app, nothing can be seen, except for the title. I tried to fix this by setting the `tintColor`, but to no avail.

Here's what I have so far.

```
@IBOutlet weak var swapButton: UIButton!
```

In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
var rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.layer.frame.width, 20)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rectangle.size)
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rectangle.origin.x, rectangle.origin.y)
var rectangle2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

swapButton.setBackgroundImage(rectangle2, forState: .Normal)
swapButton.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
var yourbutton = UIButton(frame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 35))

var rect  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
var context : CGContextRef  = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

var image : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

yourbutton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

self.view.addSubview(yourbutton)
```